# select the previous start date element value and check with the end date value in jquery

Tags: jquery, date, element

I have two dates(start date and end date) displaying on a page,i want to check if end date is greater than start date should display and alert

```
<div class="span6">
      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
      <input class="startdate" id="datepicker" name="form-0-date_start" placeholder="Date Start" type="text" />                
</div>

<div class="input-prepend marg_tp38 span6">
   <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
   <input class="enddate" id="datepicker" name="form-0-date_end" placeholder="End Date" type="text" />                                                         
</div>

**jquery code**

      $(".enddate").focusout(function(){
            console.log($(this).val());
            var start_date = $(this).prevAll("input[type=text]").first().val();
            var end_date = $(this).val();  
            console.log($(this).parent().find('input').val());
            console.log(answer+">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
            if (end_date < start_date)
               {
                   alert('End date should not be greater than start date');  
                } 
      });
```

In the above jquery method, i cant able to get start_date value, so how to get the previous element value in jquery(I want to do it only in the way of finding the previous element date value) ?

How to check the date end is less than date start date , whats wrong in my code, and why am i getting the start_date value as `undefined` ?

Comment: Can I point out that you have two elements with the same `id`? This invalidates your HTML.

Comment: yep both elements have same id, they are used for some design, so dont want to disturb them, so want to implement in the above way of finding the previous element, also there may be many divs that contains start date and end date ...

Comment: Your rationale is irrelevant; a duplicate `id` is invalid, reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2